# Scrapy error catching in scrapy/middleware.py file: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'uri'

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-middleware

I am catching this error while starting a crawl. I have searched for an answer in several forums, and looked at the code in `scrapy/middleware.py` (came standard with `scrapy` and I have not altered it) and cannot figure out why I am getting an error.

The scraper is using both an `ImagesPipeline` and `S3FilesStore` pipeline for storing a json file and downloaded images directly into different S3 folders. I am using Python 3.6.

Any help is appreciated. The error message and my scraper settings are below, please let me know if anything else would be useful.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 77, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 102, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 40, in from_settings
    mw = mwcls()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'uri'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.S3FilesStore': 1,
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1
}

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= 'xxxxxx'

IMAGES_STORE = 's3 path'

FEED_URI = 's3 path'
FEED_FORMAT = 'jsonlines'
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = None
FEED_STORE_EMPTY = False
FEED_STORAGES = {}
FEED_STORAGES_BASE = {
'': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FileFeedStorage',
'file': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FileFeedStorage',
'stdout': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.StdoutFeedStorage',
's3': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.S3FeedStorage',
'ftp': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FTPFeedStorage',
}
FEED_EXPORTERS = {}
FEED_EXPORTERS_BASE = {
    'json': 'scrapy.exporters.JsonItemExporter',
    'jsonlines': 'scrapy.exporters.JsonLinesItemExporter',
    'jl': None,
    'csv': None,
    'xml': None,
    'marshal': None,
    'pickle': None,
}
```

Comment: remove settings one by one till you get working code - this way you find line which makes problem.

Comment: Thanks, this worked once I changed it to just an images pipeline feeding into S3. I am continuing to explore other options for getting an output file stored in the same S3 bucket (but different folder) as well.